# Passing an Array from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm trying to pass on a PHP array to then use the array in JavaScript.

The PHP code I'm using is as follows:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $data[] = $row;
        }
        print_r($row);
        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($link);

//convert the PHP array into JSON format, so it works with javascript
$json_array = json_encode($data);
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script> 
    var array = <?php echo $data; ?>; 
    console.log(array); 
</script>
```

The `data array` in PHP doesn't seem to get passed on to the Javascript `var array`. When looking at the console on firebug the following error messages are displayed:

> Notice - Array to string conversion.

I'd really appreciate any help as to why this error is occurring.

Comment: Could you post the _rendered_ version of this code?

Comment: You need to `echo $json_array;` not `echo $data;`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<?php echo $json_array; ?>`?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Very stupid mistake, ill put it down to tiredness .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```
<script> var array = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
console.log(array); </script>
```

You're using json_encode in $data but you're not using that variable in your code. Could that be it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you are echo'ing the array instead of the json encoded string.

Use this

```
<script> var array = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
console.log(array); </script>
```